# Find max indices in octave

Tags: max, octave

I have nx4 matrix. I need to find max value and it's index. I use 
    `[mVal,mInd]=max(A,[],2)`
When a row contains same value more than once and it is the max value I need to find all indices of the row.

Example: Say `A(10,:)` is `[-1.2 1.6 1.6 1.6]` I need to return 2,3,4 as indices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
A(10,:)=[-1.2 1.6 1.6 1.6];
[i,j]=find(A==max(max(A)))
```

The row indices of the maxima should be in the vector `i`, the column indices in `j`.