# OCTAVE: row, column index return

Tags: indexing, return

I want to return row, column index.
For example
a = [1 2 3; 7 8 9; 4 5 6]
In this matrix, Maximum is 9.
I want to return row 2, column 3 of 9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find max indices in octave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769580/find-max-indices-in-octave)

Comment: This post is some kind of a math question

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward.
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Index-Expressions.html

```
a(2,3)
```